# Gradle Script to Automate Android Versioning by git tags

Tags: android, git, gradle, build.gradle, versioning

I got stuck on a Problem with this script. I want to achieve 3 things:

1. fetch the latest tag from git and split the string up into 3 values (Major, Mino, Patch) - Every tag will have that format. Save the fetched data to the properties ext.versionMajor etc.
2. generate a versionCode
3. generate a versionNumber

My goal is to never care about versioning manually my builds. By just keep setting tags via git, this gradle script should automatically update the versionCode and versionNumber.

**The Problem**
When I let gradle compile that script it fails with an *Error on Line 77* and the Error just says *0*.

```
 ext.versionMajor = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
```

I don´t get it, why does it fail there? Am I assigning the value wrong to the properties?

Im not a gradle pro, I would be really happy if someone has an idea what I am doing wrong.

[Link to script 1](https://gist.github.com/maxirosson/48c0d8160c758a9145e6)
[link to script 2](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2013/07/30/automatic-versioning-with-git-and-gradle/)

Here is the code of the build.gradle file in the app folder of my Adnroid Project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext.versionMajor = 0
ext.versionMinor = 0
ext.versionPatch = 0
ext.versionClassifier = null
ext.isSnapshot = true
ext.minimumSdkVersion = 21

//fetch version tag
setVersionNumberByTag()

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webdesign.crf.eins"
        minSdkVersion minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode generateVersionCode()
        versionName generateVersionName()
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


private Integer generateVersionCode() {
    return minimumSdkVersion * 10000000 + versionMajor;
}

private String generateVersionName() {
    String versionName = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    if (ext.versionClassifier == null) {
        if (isSnapshot) {
            versionClassifier = "SNAPSHOT"
        }
    }

    if (ext.versionClassifier != null) {
        versionName += "-" + versionClassifier
    }
    return versionName;
}

private String setVersionNumberByTag() {
    /*
 * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
 */
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    String verByGit = stdout.toString().trim()
    String[] v = new String[3];
    v = verByGit.split(".");
    ext.versionMajor = Integer.parseInt(v[0]);
    ext.versionMinor = Integer.parseInt(v[1]);
    ext.versionPatch = Integer.parseInt(v[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**found a solution**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

ext.versionMajor = null
ext.versionMinor = 0
ext.versionPatch = 1
ext.versionClassifier = null
ext.isSnapshot = true
ext.minimumSdkVersion = 21


android {
    //fetch version tag
    setVersionNumberByTag()
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webdesign.crf.eins"
        minSdkVersion minimumSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode generateVersionCode()
        versionName generateVersionName()
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


private Integer generateVersionCode() {
    return ext.minimumSdkVersion * 10000000 + ext.versionMajor * 10000 + ext.versionMinor * 100 + ext.versionPatch
}

private String generateVersionName() {
    String versionName = "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
    if (ext.versionClassifier == null) {
        if (isSnapshot) {
            versionClassifier = "SNAPSHOT"
        }
    }

    if (ext.versionClassifier != null) {
        versionName += "-" + versionClassifier
    }
    return versionName;
}

private String setVersionNumberByTag() {
    /*
 * Gets the version name from the latest Git tag
 */
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    def String verByGit = stdout.toString().trim()
    def (major, minor, patch) = verByGit.tokenize(".");
    ext.versionMajor = Integer.parseInt(major);
    ext.versionMinor = Integer.parseInt(minor);
    ext.versionPatch = Integer.parseInt(patch);
}
```

In gradle files [groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) is used. That means its not possible to use `someString.split(".");` like normal in java. I found out, that `def (major, minor, patch) = verByGit.tokenize(".");` did the trick.

Comment: I actually haves the same issue and created a gradle plugin to do almost the same. Check it out and tell me what you think https://github.com/rperez93/gradle-utils